# How to set grading value in Excel?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I'm a university student (Business Admin) and I want to set up a worksheet to help me keep track of my academic performance.

How do I set up column C to show value corresponding to value in column B?

Example,

```
column A (subject),   column B (Grade),   column C (value)
Markting                  B-                 3.33
```

A=4.00, A−=3.67, B+=3.33, B=3.00, B−=2.67, etc...

Comment: You can create a master table of Grade & Value and simply use VLOOKUP function to look up respective Grade and fetch the Value from that table into your Column C.

Comment: The fact that your example does not match your defined mapping is not a good start.

Answer (score 0):

With data in **B1**, in **C1** enter:

```
=LOOKUP(B1,{"A","A-","B","B-","B+"},{4,3.67,3,2.67,3.33})
```

and copy down:

[image]

NOTE:

The input vector must be in **alphabetic order**.